# How do I replicate the Super Key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, xmonad

If you use xmonad, xbindkeys, and xdotool to try and remap the 'Menu' key, it does not work perfectly.  The 'Menu' key will only emulate the <kbd>Super</kbd> key's quick press action, bringing up the application search. If you hold in the 'Menu' key it will not emulate the Super key's hold down action.  That is, bring up the launcer with numbers over the applications.

How do you make another key on the keyboard act **exactly** like the Super key?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that doing this:

1) Open "System Settings"

[image]

2) Keyboard Layout

[image]

3) Options

[image]

4) Alt/Win key behavior then choose "Alt is mapped to right Win, Super to Menu".

[image]

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.10, is this still possible?

Comment: I think you will have to add a keyboard with a "Macintosh" or another suitable layout ("Text Entry" > "+").